# JQuery Selector to select dropdown by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of Yes/No dropdowns and I'd like to select all select elements with a value of Yes.

```
<select name="foo1">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<select name="foo2">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<select name="foo3">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

I'd like a JQuery selector that returns a subset of select nodes which are currently in a state of Yes.  I realize I can do a simple call to filter(), but I would much rather do it all in a selector.

```
$('#myform select').filter(function(k,v){return v.value == 'yes';})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? I would use `filter` method, faster and promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myform select option[value="yes"]:selected').parent()
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RqPTC/)

Comment: Man, I could have sworn I tried this.  I tried so many things, some completely off the wall. Who knows what I was doing in the end.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be efficient, you should stick to `filter`, but you can create a custom filter that you can use directly in your selector:

```
$.expr[':'].value = $.expr.createPseudo(function (value) {
    return function (el) {
        return el.value == value;
    };
});
```

Use it as follows:

```
$('select:value(yes)');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Eb3hp/

Comment: This looks really awesome.  I'm thinking overkill for my purpose, but I'll +1 for coolness value.

Answer (score 1):

it would be

```
$('#form select:has(option[value=yes]:selected)')
```

It will get all select that has option:selected with a value=yes

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FDmDS/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myform select[value=yes]');
```